# How to add category select in admin block page without UI component?

Tags: category, blocks, magento2.4.5, category-filter, category-selector

I am trying to add category selector in my block page without UI component.
This is my block file.

```
   <?php

namespace Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Element\Dependence;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface;
use Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Config as WysiwygConfig;
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable;
use Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Dependency\FieldFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Convert\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Render\Image as BannerImage;
use Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Render\Slider;
use Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser;
use Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Helper\Data;
use Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Helper\Image as HelperImage;
use Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Model\Config\Source\Template;
use Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Model\Config\Source\Type;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime;

/**
 * Class Banner
 * @package Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab
 */
class Banner extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    /**
     * Type options
     *
     * @var Type
     */
    protected $typeOptions;

    /**
     * Template options
     *
     * @var Template
     */
    protected $template;

    /**
     * Status options
     *
     * @var Enabledisable
     */
    protected $statusOptions;

    /**
     * @var HelperImage
     */
    protected $imageHelper;

    /**
     * @var FieldFactory
     */
    protected $_fieldFactory;

    /**
     * @var DataObject
     */
    protected $_objectConverter;

    /**
     * @var WysiwygConfig
     */
    protected $_wysiwygConfig;

    /**
     * Banner constructor.
     *
     * @param Type $typeOptions
     * @param Template $template
     * @param Enabledisable $statusOptions
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Registry $registry
     * @param FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param HelperImage $imageHelper
     * @param FieldFactory $fieldFactory
     * @param DataObject $objectConverter
     * @param WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Type $typeOptions,
        Template $template,
        Enabledisable $statusOptions,
        Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        FormFactory $formFactory,
        HelperImage $imageHelper,
        FieldFactory $fieldFactory,
        DataObject $objectConverter,
        WysiwygConfig $wysiwygConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->typeOptions = $typeOptions;
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->statusOptions = $statusOptions;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->_fieldFactory = $fieldFactory;
        $this->_objectConverter = $objectConverter;
        $this->_wysiwygConfig = $wysiwygConfig;

        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare title for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->getTabLabel();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare label for tab
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('General');
    }

    /**
     * Can show tab in tabs
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return Generic
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        /** @var \Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Model\Banner $banner */
        $banner = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('mpbannerslider_banner');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('banner_');
        $form->setFieldNameSuffix('banner');
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', [
            'legend' => __('Banner Information'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
        ]);

        if ($banner->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField(
                'banner_id',
                'hidden',
                ['name' => 'banner_id']
            );
        }

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', [
            'name' => 'name',
            'label' => __('Banner Title'),
            'title' => __('Banner Title'),
            'required' => true,
        ]);

        $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', [
            'name' => 'status',
            'label' => __('Status'),
            'title' => __('Status'),
            'values' => $this->statusOptions->toOptionArray(),
        ]);

        $fieldset->addField(
            'category_ids',
            '\Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser',
            [
                'name' => 'category_ids',
                'label' => __('Categories'),
                'title' => __('Categories'),
                'required' => true
            ]
        );
        

        $uploadBanner = $fieldset->addField('image', BannerImage::class, [
            'name' => 'image',
            'label' => __('Upload Image'),
            'title' => __('Upload Image'),
            'path' => $this->imageHelper->getBaseMediaPath(HelperImage::TEMPLATE_MEDIA_TYPE_BANNER)
        ]);

        $titleBanner = $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', [
            'name' => 'title',
            'label' => __('Banner SubTitle'),
            'title' => __('Banner SubTitle'),
        ]);

        $urlBanner = $fieldset->addField('url_banner', 'text', [
            'name' => 'url_banner',
            'label' => __('Url'),
            'title' => __('Url'),
            'class' => 'validate-url validate-no-html-tags'
        ]);

        $newTab = $fieldset->addField('newtab', 'select', [
            'name' => 'newtab',
            'label' => __('Open new tab after click'),
            'title' => __('Open new tab after click'),
            'values' => $this->statusOptions->toOptionArray(),
            'note' => __('Automatically open new tab after clicking on the banner')

        ]);

        $orderBanner = $fieldset->addField('vieworder', 'text', [
            'name' => 'vieworder',
            'label' => __('Display Order'),
            'title' => __('Display Order'),
        ]);
        $fieldset->addField('banner_from_date', 'date', [
            'name' => 'banner_from_date',
            'label' => __('Banner Start Date'),
            'title' => __('Banner Start Date'),
            'date_format' => 'yyyy/MM/dd',
            'input_format' => DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
            'timezone' => false
        ]);

        $fieldset->addField('banner_to_date', 'date', [
            'name' => 'banner_to_date',
            'label' => __('Banner End Date'),
            'title' => __('Banner End Date'),
            'date_format' => 'yyyy/MM/dd',
            'input_format' => DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
            'timezone' => false
        ]);
        

        $fieldset->addField('sliders_ids', Slider::class, [
            'name' => 'sliders_ids',
            'label' => __('Sliders'),
            'title' => __('Sliders'),
        ]);
        if (!$banner->getSlidersIds()) {
            $banner->setSlidersIds($banner->getSliderIds());
        }

        $bannerData = $this->_session->getData('mpbannerslider_banner_data', true);
        if ($bannerData) {
            $banner->addData($bannerData);
        } else {
            if (!$banner->getId()) {
                $banner->addData($banner->getDefaultValues());
            }
        }

        $form->addValues($banner->getData());
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I add fieldset name of category_ids.
And then this is my chooser.php

```
    <?php
namespace Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category as CategoryModel;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Multiselect;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Chooser extends Multiselect
{

    public $collectionFactory;

    public $authorization;

    protected $_urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        Factory $factoryElement,
        CollectionFactory $factoryCollection,
        Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;

        parent::__construct($factoryElement, $factoryCollection, $escaper, $data);
    }

    public function getElementHtml()
    {
        $html = '<div class="admin__field-control admin__control-grouped">';
        $html .= '<div id="topbanner-category-select" class="admin__field" data-bind="scope:\'topbannerCategory\'" data-index="index">';
        $html .= '<!-- ko foreach: elems() -->';
        $html .= '<input name="category_ids" data-bind="value: value" style="display: none"/>';
        $html .= '<!-- ko template: elementTmpl --><!-- /ko -->';
        $html .= '<!-- /ko -->';
        $html .= '</div></div>';

        $html .= $this->getAfterElementHtml();

        return $html;
    }

    public function getCategoriesTree()
    {
        /* @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection */
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('name')->addAttributeToSort('position','asc');

        $categoryById = [
            CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID => [
                'value'    => CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID,
                'optgroup' => null,
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            foreach ([$category->getId(), $category->getParentId()] as $categoryId) {
                if (!isset($categoryById[$categoryId])) {
                    $categoryById[$categoryId] = ['value' => $categoryId];
                }
            }

            $categoryById[$category->getId()]['is_active'] = 1;
            $categoryById[$category->getId()]['label'] = $category->getName();
            $categoryById[$category->getParentId()]['optgroup'][] = &$categoryById[$category->getId()];
        }

        return $categoryById[CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID]['optgroup'];
    }

    public function getValues()
    {
        $values = $this->getValue();
        if (!is_array($values)) {
            $values = explode(',', $values);
        }

        if (!sizeof($values)) {
            return [];
        }

        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
            ->addIdFilter($values);

        $options = [];
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $options[] = $category->getId();
        }

        return $options;
    }

    public function getAfterElementHtml()
    {
        $html = '<script type="text/x-magento-init">
            {
                "*": {
                    "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                        "components": {
                            "topbannerCategory": {
                                "component": "uiComponent",
                                "children": {
                                    "select_category": {
                                        "component": "Vendor_Module/js/components/new-category",
                                        "config": {
                                            "filterOptions": true,
                                            "disableLabel": true,
                                            "chipsEnabled": true,
                                            "levelsVisibility": "1",
                                            "elementTmpl": "ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select",
                                            "options": ' . json_encode($this->getCategoriesTree()) . ',
                                            "value": ' . json_encode($this->getValues()) . ',
                                            "listens": {
                                                "index=create_category:responseData": "setParsed",
                                                "newOption": "toggleOptionSelected"
                                            },
                                            "config": {
                                                "dataScope": "select_category",
                                                "sortOrder": 10
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>';

        return $html;
    }

}
```

After run, error is occured.

```
    [2023-07-03T09:42:33.892733+00:00] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Deprecated Functionality: explode(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($string) of type string is deprecated in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser.php on line 83 in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler.php:62
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8192, 'explode(): Pass...', 'F:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 83)
#1 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser.php(83): explode(',', NULL)
#2 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser.php(120): Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser->getValues()
#3 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\form\renderer\fieldset\element.phtml(12): Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser->getAfterElementHtml()
#4 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(71): include('F:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#5 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element), 'F:/xampp/htdocs...', Array)
#6 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(293): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('F:/xampp/htdocs...')
#7 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Template.php(141): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#8 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1095): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#9 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#10 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#11 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element.php(46): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#12 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement.php(541): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset\Element->render(Object(Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser))
#13 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement.php(555): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->getHtml()
#14 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset.php(232): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->toHtml()
#15 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset.php(109): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset->_elementsToHtml(Array)
#16 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor.php(59): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset->getBasicChildrenHtml()
#17 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\form\renderer\fieldset.phtml(84): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor->getBasicChildrenHtml()
#18 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(71): include('F:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#19 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset), 'F:/xampp/htdocs...', Array)
#20 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(293): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('F:/xampp/htdocs...')
#21 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Template.php(141): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#22 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1095): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#23 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#24 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#25 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset.php(50): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#26 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement.php(541): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset->render(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor))
#27 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor.php(338): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->getHtml()
#28 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement.php(555): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor->getHtml()
#29 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor.php(347): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement->toHtml()
#30 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form.php(373): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor->toHtml()
#31 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form.php(390): Magento\Framework\Data\Form->toHtml()
#32 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form.php(113): Magento\Framework\Data\Form->getHtml()
#33 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor.php(68): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->getFormHtml()
#34 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\form.phtml(13): Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor->getFormHtml()
#35 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(71): include('F:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#36 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor), 'F:/xampp/htdocs...', Array)
#37 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor.php(221): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('F:/xampp/htdocs...')
#38 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(293): Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor->fetchView('F:/xampp/htdocs...')
#39 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Template.php(141): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#40 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1095): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#41 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#42 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#43 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor.php(446): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#44 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs.php(492): Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor->toHtml()
#45 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\tabs.phtml(73): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor))
#46 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(71): include('F:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#47 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tabs), 'F:/xampp/htdocs...', Array)
#48 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(293): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('F:/xampp/htdocs...')
#49 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Template.php(141): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#50 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1095): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#51 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#52 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#53 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(578): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#54 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(555): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('Uedakanamono_ba...')
#55 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('Uedakanamono_ba...')
#56 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('Uedakanamono_ba...')
#57 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('Uedakanamono_ba...', false)
#58 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('Uedakanamono_ba...', false)
#59 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('left', false)
#60 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#61 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#62 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('left', false)
#63 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('left', false)
#64 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('side.col', false)
#65 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#66 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#67 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('side.col', false)
....
#102 {main} [] []
```

**Who can answer this issue?**

Comment: Hello Malcom, you are using explode function on null value plz use it in condition.

Answer (score 0):

> Please update the below line in  **getValue()** at **Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser.php**

```
$values = $this->getValue(); 

to

$values = $this->getValue() ?? '';
```